# Error using AutomationManagementClient with CertificateCloudCredentials

Tags: c#, azure, azure-automation

I'm trying to start an azure runbook from a MVC app.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertBase64String"]));
var creds = new CertificateCloudCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionId"], cert);

AutomationManagementClient automationManagementClient = new AutomationManagementClient(creds);

var content = automationManagementClient.Runbooks.GetAsync(<Resource group name>, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutomationAccount"], <Runbook name>)
```

I get this error:

> AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing.

I got this code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt465763.aspx)  but I can't seem to make it work.
(The certificate is the one downloaded from [here](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=vs&schemaversion=2.0) ).

I tried using `TokenCloudCredentials` from a Console app and that seems to work fine but I'm not sure if I can use those in the MVC app.

Any ideas how I should use `AutomationManagementClient` with certificate credentials? Or how to use `TokenCloudCredentials` in the web app?

Comment: Where do you get "CertBase64String"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Automation SDK you are attempting to use uses Azure Resource Manager APIs, which do not support management certificate-based authentication. You will need to authenticate via `TokenCloudCredentials`. The documentation that shows management certificate support is incorrect and we will update it shortly.

Comment: Do you have an example for using this from a webapp?

Comment: No, but I think it should work. Even if it doesn't you could use webhooks to start runbooks instead. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-webhooks/ for more details

Comment: Joe, thank you for clarification. However, MSDN states that management certificate-based auth should work (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt465763.aspx): "If you are plan to use certificate-based authentication, update the SubscriptionId and CertBase64Stringvalues. Both these values are available in PublishSettings file."

It would be great if MSDN docs could be updated accordingly.